# Fell into a pit and one's artificial organs were damaged -- consequences?

Tags: halacha, parts-of-the-body, torts-damages

That's something I've studied many years ago - [laws of damages by a pit](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8_(%D7%90%D7%91_%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9F)). IIRC in one falls into a pit (בור) the owner pays only body damages but not broken tools.

What artificial limbs/organs qualify as "original body organs" to require paying damages and what are considered tools to exempt the owner from paying? For example - teeth, eyes, arms, heart?

Comment: מחובר לגוף לא מקבל טומאה, לא עושה חציצה הטבילה.  So I think that they are not kelim

Comment: Surely there must be a classical discussion about clothing.